# Relationship between logarithms and harmonic series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

[This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) on the harmonic series says that

$$\sum_{n=1}^k\,\frac{1}{n} \;=\; \ln k + \gamma + \varepsilon_k$$

where
$$\varepsilon_k\sim\frac{1}{2k}$$

and this seems to generalise to
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\,\frac{1}{\ln(x)n} \;=\; \log_x k + \frac{\gamma}{\ln(x)} + \varepsilon_k $$

Why is this the case?

Comment: What is `log(x)n`? Is it log of `n` with base `x`? Or `logx` (and in what base?) multiplied by `n`?

Comment: Updated - hopefully a bit clearer.
$\log_x$ is $\log$ base $x$.

Comment: It seems that all you've done is divide the first formula by $\ln (x)$

Comment: Ah ha! .... Cogs slowly turning ... :/

Comment: ;)${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the area below $1/x$ between 1 and $n$, and compare the curve to the "staircase" $1/k$. The area under the staircase is your sum, the area under the curve is just $\ln n$. If you look at the curve $1/(x - 1)$, it is above the staircase, an approximation from above to the staircase area is $1+\int_2^n \frac{d x}{1-x} = 1 + \ln (n - 1)$. Averaging both areas gives a rough estimate of $\ln n + 1/2 + \ln \frac{n - 1}{n} \approx \ln n + 1/2 - 1/n$ for the sum.

[image: Continuous and staircase]

The image shows the relationship between a continuous function (green) and the staircase (red) described.

Comment: Why does this generalise to the $\log$ to any base?